# Why I still have system interpreter?

Tags: python, macos, pyenv

I'm using pyenv for managing python versions.
I have installed oh-my-zsh. And I don't know why, but I think it isn't clear

```sh
~ pyenv versions                                                                                                                                               
  system
* 3.8.5 (set by /Users/kir/.pyenv/version)
```

If I try use Python

```sh
~ python -V                                                                                                                                                    
Python 2.7.16
```

I think it works different.
Is it normal behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

After googling, I found [this issue](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/896)
and I just add

```
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

to my .zshrc file in home directory and it worked!